# How to generate row number as a column for an existing table?

Tags: mysql, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to create Row number(`row_num`) as a column for an existing table in MySql via spark for reading the database parallelly (i.e partitioning column since all the columns in the table are String).

When I tried to execute this query:

```
val query = SELECT @row_number:=@row_number+1 as rowid,d.* FROM destination d, (SELECT @row_number:=0) as init
```

I got an exception like below:

```
17/10/16 10:50:00 INFO SparkSqlParser: Parsing command: SELECT @row_number:=@row_number+1 as rowid,d. FROM destination d, (SELECT @row_number:=0) as init
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException:
no viable alternative at input 'SELECT @'(line 1, pos 7)

== SQL ==
SELECT @row_number:=@row_number+1 as rowid,d. FROM destination d, (SELECT @row_number:=0) as init
-------^^^

at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException.withCommand(ParseDriver.scala:197)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AbstractSqlParser.parse(ParseDriver.scala:99)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkSqlParser.parse(SparkSqlParser.scala:45)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AbstractSqlParser.parsePlan(ParseDriver.scala:53)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:592)
at com.syntel.spark.sparkDVT$.main(sparkDVT.scala:61)
at com.syntel.spark.sparkDVT.main(sparkDVT.scala)
```

Code which I tried:

```
val p2 = "@row_number"
val a = s"""SELECT $p2:=$p2+1 as rowid,d.* FROM destination d, (SELECT $p2:=0) as init"""
val df1 = spark.sql(a)
```

By referring :

https://forums.databricks.com/questions/115/how-do-i-pass-parameters-to-my-sql-statements.html

How to execute the below query from spark in mysql

```
val query = SELECT @row_number:=@row_number+1 as rowid,d.* FROM destination d, (SELECT @row_number:=0) as init
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to create Row number(row_num) as a column for an existing table in MySql via spark

### row_number Function

Use [row_number](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@row_number():org.apache.spark.sql.Column):

> **row_number(): Column** Window function: returns a sequential number starting at 1 within a window partition.

You could use it as follows:

```
val input = spark.range(10)
scala> input.printSchema
root
 |-- id: long (nullable = false)

import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
val byId = Window.orderBy($"id".asc)
scala> input.withColumn("index", row_number over byId).show
17/10/16 08:27:01 WARN WindowExec: No Partition Defined for Window operation! Moving all data to a single partition, this can cause serious performance degradation.
+---+-----+
| id|index|
+---+-----+
|  0|    1|
|  1|    2|
|  2|    3|
|  3|    4|
|  4|    5|
|  5|    6|
|  6|    7|
|  7|    8|
|  8|    9|
|  9|   10|
+---+-----+
```

Be careful though as it's a window function and requires an ordered window and moves all the rows that belong to a window partition to a single Spark partition as noted by the warning:

> 17/10/16 08:27:01 WARN WindowExec: No Partition Defined for Window operation! Moving all data to a single partition, this can cause serious performance degradation.

That means that for a very large dataset you may incur long GCs or even not be able to finish at all due to OutOfMemoryError.

### monotonically_increasing_id() Function

There's another function [monotonically_increasing_id](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@monotonically_increasing_id():org.apache.spark.sql.Column):

> **monotonically_increasing_id(): Column** A column expression that generates monotonically increasing 64-bit integers.

Please note that...

> The generated ID is guaranteed to be monotonically increasing and unique, but not consecutive. The current implementation puts the partition ID in the upper 31 bits, and the record number within each partition in the lower 33 bits. The assumption is that the data frame has less than 1 billion partitions, and each partition has less than 8 billion records.

Comment: so can I use `monotonically_increasing_id()` as a partitioning column for reading the database parallelly

Comment: It's going to be too expensive and you can use the JDBC reader of Spark directly to achieve that --> https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/spark-sql-DataFrameReader.html#jdbc That begs for another question on SO though as you've asked about generating ids here. Please approve my answer if it helped.

Comment: Is there any better way to partition a table which does not contain a column of Integer type and consecutive fashion ?

Comment: What are you doing after you partition your data? That should answer your question (or lead to an answer). `groupBy` can help.

Comment: comparing two tables for differences in it so I'm reading the data from database and persisting it to DISK, so I'm reading it parallelly to do so but in case of non integer type column I don't know how. That's the reason for creating a row_number in table and reading it parallelly but I cannot execute the query in the question from spark, but `monotonically_increasing_id()` can help only after reading the table from the database.

Comment: What's the primary key in the tables? Why don't you use it? I don't see a reason to use Spark for it.

Comment: There are primary keys for most of the cases but for some cases it wont be there.

Comment: How will you know that rows could be identical? What are the criteria to say this row is this in the other table?

Comment: For Instance the primary column looks like `poo10001`..`poo500005`

Answer (score 0):

If you want execute a `mySQL` query you need use standard JDBC API.

Spark SQL API is related to [DataFrame ou DataSet](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html) (Spark Object).

The topic `How do I pass parameters to my SQL statements?`doesn't talk about `mySql` but `my SQL`